# SQL query about selecting the highest value

Tags: sql

I have these two tables

```
create table Employee2(eid char(3), ename char(10), salary number(7,2), 
mid char(3),primary key
(eid), foreign key (mid) references Employee2); 

create table MakesD2 (aoid char(3), eid char(3), cid char(3), prices 
number, dates date, primary key
(aoid,CID), foreign key (aoid) references ArtObject2, foreign key (CID) 
references Customer2,foreign key (eid) references Employee2);
```

I need to find the employees who sold the most paintings.

I have this so far.

```
SELECT e.ename, MAX(md.eid)
FROM Employee2 e inner join MakesD2 md on md.eid=e.eid
GROUP BY e.ename;
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: don't use `char` use `varchar` instead.

Comment: @NatheeshSelvan - Questions on SO may be useful to other people. Deleting them after you have received a solution is akin to vandalism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH emp_total_sales AS 
(
    SELECT eid, sum(prices) total_price FROM MakesD2 GROUP BY eid
)
SELECT e.ename FROM Employee2 e, emp_total_sales es  
WHERE e.eid = es.eid AND es.total_price IN (SELECT MAX(total_price) FROM emp_total_sales);
```